# I am using Huxton.SR6. AWS dependencies. I want to add firebase for Push Notifications. The dependecny is not found

Tags: firebase, spring-boot

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.5
 

com.mars.apis
mars-service
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
mars-service
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.security.oauth
spring-security-oauth2
2.3.0.RELEASE


org.springframework.security
spring-security-jwt
1.0.9.RELEASE


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-validation


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


mysql
mysql-connector-java
runtime


io.springfox
springfox-swagger2
2.6.1
compile


io.springfox
springfox-swagger-ui
2.6.1
compile


org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-aws


org.projectlombok
lombok
true


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-test
test


org.springframework.security
spring-security-test
test

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <finalName>mars-service</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because of the artifact issue. It was not able to download from the remote repo. changed the settings.xml file solved the issue